# XSL for XML to Excel: Using a Curly Bracket in Formula

Tags: regex, excel, xslt, curly-brackets

How do I use curly brackets in an XSL which generates an Excel file from an XML?

I can accomplish what I want with an Excel formula, but it needs to use curly brackets list like:

```
    =LOOKUP(XXXX, {"NA","NF","NR","O"},{"NA","Completed","NR","Ongoing"}
```

Which I can not get the XSL to accept even when using the HTML indicators for the brackets and commas, I still get an error on the first comma after the first curly bracket.

```
    =LOOKUP(XXXX,&#123;&quot;NA&quot;&#44;&quot;NF&quot;&#44;&quot;NR&quot;&#44;&quot;O&quot;&#125;&#44;&#123;&quot;NA&quot;&#44;&quot;Completed&quot;&#44;&quot;NR&quot;&#44;&quot;OngoingNA&quot;&#125;)

&123; = {
&#$$; = , (comma)
```

But I get an XML Error on the first command saying: "Expected token '{' found ','.

```
    =LOOKUP(XXXX,{"NA"-->,<--"NF,"NR","O"},{"NA","Completed","NR","Ongoing","NA"})
```

Comment: Is this question about an XSLT stylesheet? If so, please show that code. Also show the XML input and expected Excel output. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you are trying to create a *literal result element* with an attribute containing curly braces. This is problematic, because the curly braces are interpreted as an *attribute value template* - i.e. the XSLT processor tries to evaluate the expression contained within.

To avoid this, you must either escape the curly braces by doubling them, or use the `xsl:attribute` instruction to specify the value as text. For example, both:

```
<elem attr="=SUM({{1,2}}*{{4,5}})"/>
```

and:

```
<elem>
    <xsl:attribute name="attr">=SUM({1,2}*{4,5})</xsl:attribute>
</elem>
```

will return the same result:

```
<elem attr="=SUM({1,2}*{4,5})"/>
```